# How to change datasource of DataGridView by buttons?

Tags: forms, datagridview, datasource

It is just a concept to switch the grid content using buttons. It works, but when the button is pushed twice, grid disapears. Why ?

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.select_Hosp_from_to_missedTableAdapter.Fill(this.dKC_APPSDataSet.select_Hosp_from_to_missed);
            this.select_JIP_from_to_missedTableAdapter.Fill(this.dKC_APPSDataSet.select_JIP_from_to_missed);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.advancedDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.advancedDataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            this.advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = this.selectHospfromtomissedBindingSource;            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.advancedDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.advancedDataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            this.advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = this.selectJIPfromtomissedBindingSource;
        }
```

Comment: I am confident you are running into the issue such that, IF you set/reassign the grids `DataSource` to the SAME “data source” it already has, THEN the grid will NOT refresh or update the UI because from its point of view… the data has NOT changed.

Comment: This can be seen in the posted code… the two lines of code are unnecessary and should be removed or moved to the form load event …. `advancedDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;` only needs to be set once in this context and should be in the form load event. The line that “Clears” the columns is unnecessary. If you are “changing” the grids `DataSource` then the previous columns will go away automatically when you assign the next data source. It is this line that is causing your problem.

Comment: Given this, when you click on one of the buttons a “second” consecutive time… the code first sets the auto generate columns, then “CLEARS” the existing columns…. This is what you are seeing, as previously stated, since the `DataSource` has not actually “changed” the UI wont update this and you end up with an empty grid. To solve this, you can set the grids data source to null then set it again to the desired source…. `advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = null;` …. This should fix this; however, it would be easier to simply “remove” the clearing of the columns as it is unnecessary for any case.